# Notify all adapters using Tablayout and Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-fragments

Im currently using an RecyclerView Adapter on 3 different fragments: "Overview", "Income", "Spending" in a Tablayout. All fragments holds an List and shows data from a SQLite DB depending on if its an Income or Spending (or all), but my problem is when I remove one item and notify it only updates on the current shown Fragment.

How should I think if I want to update all RecyclerViews/adapters and Lists once I remove an item in lets say "Overview" (which shows all items)?

Comment: post what you have researched so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send broadcast and receive them in all Fragments to notifyDataSetChanged()

While removing items send this broadcast

```
Intent intent = new Intent("key_to_identify_the_broadcast");
intent.putExtra("refresh", true);
context.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

and then for every fragment create broadcast receiver

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new 
BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Boolean refresh = 
            intent.getBooleanExtra("refresh",false);
        if(refresh){
           notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        //you can call any of your methods for using this value for your use case
  }
};
```

You need to register this broadcast in onCreateView() of fragment

```
IntentFilter filter = new 
      IntentFilter("key_to_identify_the_broadcast");
       getActivity().getApplicationContext().
              registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, filter);
```

You need to unregister in your onDestroy() of your fragment

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    try {

     getActivity().getApplicationContext().
         unregisterReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver);

   } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.e("UnRegister Error", "> " + e.getMessage());
   }
   super.onDestroy();
}
```

You can implement the same broadcast receiver for all your fragments where you want to refresh the list